# Send data to subprocess (stdio, ipc, sockets, however), receiving response synchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am decorating a third party **synchronous** (!) function.

My task is:

1. Start some "server" node.js child process (3rd party).
2. After some time the decoratable function is called (by **another** 3rd party).

THE PROBLEM:

3. In the decorator function I am getting the passed arguments, and I need to send them to the "server" and get the response from it **synchronously** (because the function is Synchronous! It won't wait, and it can't return promises. Again, I can't change this, because it's 3rd party.) in order to `return` it.

How do I do the 3rd? `stdio`, `ipc`, `net` module are all asynchronous...

Comment: Well to much of a sync code in nodejs is already a bad thing. can you post some code of decorator, or what ever you are trying to do

Comment: I think we're going to need to know more about what you're really trying to do.  Somewhat by its definition and implementation in node.js, interprocess communication is asynchronous.   Please describe what a decorator function is and what you're actually trying to do.  Probably you just need to learn how to properly write asynchronous code.